# How to send bytearray to specific receiver

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

I have a TCP Server and Client in Java. The Server can send commands to the Client, the Client will then execute the command, for example: send an image to the Server.

Im sending the data with a bytearray and thats working.

But lets imagine, I want to send an image and a file separately. How would the Server supposed to know which is the right bytearray? Or if I want to make a VoiceChat (which needs to be sending bytearrays continously) and separately sending an image?

Thats my code send bytes:

Client.java

```java
    public void writeBytes(byte[] bytes, Socket socket) throws IOException {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.write(bytes);
        out.flush();
    }
```

Thats my code to receive and convert them to an Image:

Server.java

```java
    public BufferedImage writeScreenshot(Socket socket, int length) throws IOException {
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
        byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
        in.readFully(buffer);

        return ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to design a ["protocol" for the communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol). A protocol defines what are the messages that can be exchanged and how they are represented in the lower level data stream.

A quick and easy protocol is where you first send the length of the data you are going to send, and then the data:

```
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    out.writeInt(bytes.length);
    out.write(bytes);
    out.flush();
```

The receiver now has to read the length field:

```
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
    int length = in.readInt()
    byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
    in.readFully(buffer);
```

When you get to applications like voice chat, the protocol has to get more complex. Each message has to have metadata, like what type of data it contains: image or voice or something else. Also you would likely not want to design this protocol from scratch, but use something that already exists - for example the [real-time streaming protocol (RTSP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Streaming_Protocol).